# Conexão ODBC para MaxDB com python

Tags: python, pyodbc

Olá, bom dia, estou tentando conectar ao banco do meu trabalho que é em MaxDB, utilizando o driver odbc atráves do pyodbc no python.

```
import pyodbc

def retornar_conexao_sql():
    server = "-----"
    database = "----"
    username = "---"
    password = "---"
    string_conexao = 'Driver={ODBC SQL Server Driver};Server='+server+';Database='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password
    conexao = pyodbc.connect(string_conexao)
    return conexao.cursor()

retornar_conexao_sql()
```

Esse é o erro retornado

```
conexao = pyodbc.connect(string_conexao)
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Nome da fonte de dados não encontrado e nenhum driver padrão especificado (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

mas todas as consultas retornam que so tenho o driver SQL Server e não o ODBC ou MaxDB

com isso fiz a busca dos drivers com o comando

```
print(pyodbc.drivers())
```

e unico driver que me foi retornado foi: `['SQL Server']`

Comment: Uma coisa que acabei entendendo é que o pyodbc so puxa os drivers do 64 bits, alguém tem ideia de como posso conectar a um odbc 32 bits, pois o instalar existente é somente de 32bits.

Comment: No link abaixo tem a solução do mesmo problema que você tem: [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108862/how-to-install-pyodbc-64-bit)

Comment: O link não auxilio muito, mas devido à forma de pensamento das respostas consegui resolver o problema, consegui fazer com que o pyodbc puxasse os drivers 32bits.

Answer (score 0):

Graças a Deus e muito esforço, consegui resolver.

depois de muita pesquisa consegui ver que o pyodbc64 bits que é instalado automaticamente pelo `pip install pyodbc` so consegue ler os drivers de 64bits, idependente da versão do python e bits em si.

mas instalando o python 3.3.0 + pyodbc 32bits não oficial, consegui puxar os driver 32bits, agora so nos resta testar e ver se conecta, mas vlw muito a pena toda a pesquisa.

Link do site do pyodbc32 bits (não oficial) -> [PYODBC32](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/downloads)